# Beauty risen or beauty rose- which one is correct?

Tags: past-participles, past-simple

This is a couplet. This is kind of a metaphor I wrote and it's about a girl and it speaks about her beauty.

> **Beauty risen** from the darker side of the moon.
>   I see the night clear as you came out very soon.

Is it beauty risen or beauty rose?

I think "beauty risen" is correct but [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) says it's not. They say it's "beauty rose":

> The past participle verb risen has been used without an auxiliary verb. Consider adding one or using the past simple instead.

Comment: This has changed slightly from the version that was on English.se.  I think you may want to edit it.

Comment: formatted the question. :) @phoog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty good example of the limitations of automated grammar/spelling checkers. Especially for poetry, there are many usages that they simply aren't designed to handle.

Here, though, Grammarly is half-right. It's true that "Beauty rose" would make a fair amount of sense. But it doesn't say the same thing "Beauty risen" can. Using the past simple here is good if you want to describe an *event*, something that happened, focusing on actions.

But if you want to describe an *aspect* of a person, a *description* of them, that's not what you want at all. The past participle can be used as an adjectival phrase, describing the girl you're talking about, rather than mentioning something she did at some point.

If you want to do this, though, the period at the end of the first line quoted needs to be a comma: that line by itself is *just* a description of a person and the sentence needs to do something with that to avoid being a sentence fragment. (In this case, the second line refers back to the first with "you".)

Answer (score 5):

*Beauty risen from the darker side of the moon* is a sentence fragment, but sentence fragments are common in poetry, so if it's what you really want, it's fine.  An online grammar checker is generally going to mark sentence fragments as incorrect, however.

Is that line supposed to portray an action? If so, it is incorrect. If it is intended to paint a static picture, then it's probably correct.

A similar fragment might be

> A sign nailed above the doorway